# Showing that the triangle $\Delta OAB \sim \Delta OA'B'$ for the inverted points $A', B'$ w.r.t. the circle centred at $O$.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

Let $A$ and $B$ be points inside the circle centred at $O$ such that $A, B, O$ are not collinear. Let $A', B'$ be the inverted versions of $A$ and $B$ w.r.t. the said circle. I am trying to show that the triangles $\Delta OAB$ and $\Delta OA'B'$ are similar. Since the two triangles have a common angle, $\angle AOB = \angle A'OB'$, it is enough to show that $\frac{OA}{OA'} = \frac{OB}{OB'}$.

Currently, I am not making any progress in this problem, as the only other thing I know is that $OA \cdot OA' = r^2 = OB\cdot OB'$ for the radius $r$ of the circle. Sure, we get that $\frac{OA}{OB'} = \frac{OB}{OA'}$, but to my knowledge, this is not what we need to show.

Answer (score 2):

You are very close. In fact you already showed what you need to have, it's the interpretation that's wrong. Let's assume that $A$ is on the circle, so then $A'$ will be on the circle as well. Also, say $B$ is at $r/2$ from $O$. Then $B'$ will be at $2r$. In the original triangle $OA$ was larger, in the inverted one $OB'$ is larger. So the correct way to write the formula above would be $\triangle OAB\sim\triangle OB'A'$.